# ClassCastException when converting from String to Object.. why?

Tags: exception, casting, classcastexception

I am just playing with **MessageFormat** but when I try to pass a **String** to MessageFormat **format** method it compiles fine but then I get a runtime classcast exception. Here is the code.

`MessageFormat format = new MessageFormat("");
    Object obj =  Integer.toHexString(10);
    format.format(obj);`

Now the runtime exception I get is as follows.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Object;
>       at java.text.MessageFormat.format(Unknown Source)
>       at java.text.Format.format(Unknown Source)
>       at JavaCore2.Codepoint.main(Codepoint.java:21)

Answer (score 6):

`MessageFormat.format()` takes an argument of type `Object[]` (an `Object` array), whereas you are passing in a single `Object`.

You will have to create an array out of your `Integer`:

```
MessageFormat format = new MessageFormat("{0}");
Object[] args = { Integer.toHexString(10) };

String result = format.format(args);
```

Comment: This is correct answer javadoc clearly says that single argument format(obj) `is equivalent to 
format(obj, new StringBuffer(), new FieldPosition(0)).toString();` which in turn(if you jump to another javadoc) is equivalent to format((Object[]) arguments, result, pos). What a nice people work in Oracle!

Comment: Agreed. This gets me every time.